# How to use an output filename that is only different in the extension?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, variables

I'm trying to create an Automator service that converts a MTS file to MP4 from the macOS Finder. To do so I need to setup a little bash script, but I don't know how to use input filename (for example, "file.MTS") and then generate a file called "file.mp4" with HandBrakeCLI.

I'm doing something wrong when I'm trying to assign the filename without the extension to a variable and then using it, but I don't know what is the problem:

```
for if in "$@"
do
     dest=`"$(basename "$if" | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/')"`
     /Applications/HandBrakeCLI -i "$if" -o "$dest".mp4 --preset="Fast 1080p30"
done
```

Comment: Remove the backticks on the right hand side of the `dest` assignment.

Comment: `if` is a keyword - don't use it as a variable as it obfuscates your code at best.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `sed`; `basename` already knows how to strip a given extension.

```
for if in "$@"; do
    dest=$(basename "$if" .MTS).mp4
    /Applications/HandBrakeCLI -i "$if" -o "$dest" --preset="Fast 1080p30"
done
```

As mentioned in a comment, the backticks are unnecessary and incorrect.

For example,

```
$ basename /path/to/foo.txt .txt
foo
```

If you don't know the actual extension ahead of time, parameter expansion is sufficient.

```
dest=$(basename "$if")
dest=${dest%.*}  # Strip at most one extension
```

or

```
dest=${dest%%.*}  # Strip *all* extensions
```

Comment: Thank you that works. One last question: how to save the file in he working directory?

If the file is /home/peter/files/video.MTS -> then I should get /home/peter/files/video,mp4 

Currently the script is saving it to /home/peter/video.mp4

 I've tried to use pwd=$(pwd) and the append that to the -o option but again my knowledge of bash scripting is really poor. Could you help me with that?

Comment: The working directory would appear to be `/home/peter`, and not the directory containing the input files. How exactly are you calling the script?

Comment: From Automator straight away, so it is run as a context menu option on a given file that is on certain folder. I'm not executing it from a terminal.

Comment: Ok, it still sounds like your home directory is the working directory, and the arguments are something like what `/home/peter/files/*.MTS` produces. You'll want to use the directory name that `basename` discards to construct the value of `dest`. Something like `d=$(dirname "$if"); dest="$d/$dest"`.

Comment: I'm trying this but it's not working: 

for if in "$@"; do
    d=$(dirname"$if")
    dest=$(basename "$if" .MTS).mp4
    /Applications/HandBrakeCLI -i "$if" -o "$d/$dest" --preset="Fast 1080p30"
done

Comment: Forget it, it's working now. I had to put a space between dirname and "$if". So it was d=$(dirname "$if")

Thank you!!